# Rails4 - What is the meaning of # and > in paperclip styles?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

What is the meaning of # and > in the following?

```
has_attached_file :avatar, 
:styles => {
  :thumb    => ['100x100#',  :jpg, :quality => 70],
  :preview  => ['480x480#',  :jpg, :quality => 70],
  :large    => ['600>',      :jpg, :quality => 70],
  :retina   => ['1200>',     :jpg, :quality => 30]
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stays on the official wiki:

- trailing `#`, thumbnail will be centrally cropped, ensuring the requested dimensions.
- trailing `>`, thumbnail will only be modified if it is currently larger requested dimensions. (i.e. the :small thumb for a `120×80` original image will be unchanged)

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Thumbnail-Generation

Answer (score 1):

Paperclip uses ImageMagick to process the images. [From their docs](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php):

> Use > to shrink an image only if its dimension(s) are larger than the corresponding width and/or height arguments.

As blelump mentioned you should also the [the paperclip docs](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Thumbnail-Generation)